# Implementing static properties in ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, clojurescript, prototypal-inheritance, clojurescript-javascript-interop

How can I mimic this JavaScript inheritance in ClojureScript?

```
class AccessController extends EventEmitter {

  static async create (db, options) { }

  static get type () {
    throw new Error('\'static get type ()\' needs to be defined in the inheriting class')
  }

  get type () {
    return this.constructor.type
  }

  async canAppend (entry, identityProvider) {
    return true
  }

}

class OtherController extends AccessController {

 constructor (db, options) {
    super()
  }

  static async create (db, options) {
    return new OtherController (db, options)
  }

  static get type () {
    return 'othertype'
  }

  async canAppend(entry, identityProvider) {
    return true
  }
}
```

Mu understanding is that:

- `static` is a property of the object itself
- prototype properties (methods) can be overriden by setting the `-.prototype`

This would be achieved like that:

```
(defn- OtherController
  {:jsdoc ["@constructor"]}
  [orbitdb options]
  (this-as this
    (.call AccessController this orbitdb options)
    this))

(defn create-access-controller []
  (gobj/extend
      ;; inheritance
      (.-prototype OtherController)
      (.-prototype AccessController)

    ;; methods
    #js {:canAppend (fn [entry identity-provider]                          
                      true)})

    ;; static properties
    (set! (.. OtherController -type) "othertype")

    (set! (.. OtherController -create) (fn [db options]
                                         (new OtherController db (clj->js {}))))
  OtherController)
```

I'm not sure how to:

- mimic the `get` sugar,
- since `AccessController extends EventEmitter` how can I inherit the `static` properties of `EventEmitter`, if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `get` you can create via [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).
- `static` properties aren't usually inherited I think but you can probably just do the same `gobj/extend` call for the classes themselves, not their prototype.

Comment: With ES6 `class` syntax, static properties are inherited as well.